# array passed to angular via api has all empty values

Tags: angular, asp.net-apicontroller

[image]I am using angular 5 and I have the following component:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    public locations: Location[];
    public flightChoice: FlightChoice;

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/FlightChoice/dest_locations').subscribe(result => {
            this.locations = result.json() as Location[];
            console.log(this.locations.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < this.locations.length - 1; i++) {
                console.log(this.locations[i].ID + " " +
                    this.locations[i].Name + " " +
                    this.locations[i].Country + " " +
                    this.locations[i].Airport);
            } 
        }, error => console.error(error));

    }
```

the html for which is:

```
<h1>Locations</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!locations"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="locations">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Airport</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let location of locations">
            <td>{{ location.ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.Country }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.Airport }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the api controller is:

```
 public class FlightChoiceController : BaseApiController
    {
        public FlightChoiceController(FlyDBContext ctx):base(ctx)
        {

        }

        // GET: api/<controller>
        [HttpGet("dest_locations")]
        public IEnumerable<Location> GetDestLocations()
        {
            var locs = DBContext.Locations
                    .Where(l => l.Name != "Napoli").ToArray();
            return locs;
        }


    }
}
```

The route for the controller is declared in the base controller:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : Controller
    {
        protected FlyDBContext DBContext;

        public BaseApiController(FlyDBContext ctx)
        {
            DBContext = ctx;
        }
    }
```

When in my browser I call the route for the controller I correctly get the json for all the values, but in angular, I get an array with the right length but with all empty values. The table in html gets filled with 12 empty lines.
The values of the array are all undefined.

What can be the reason? What am I doing wrong? Any clue? Thanks

Comment: Does console.log(console.log(this.locations[i]) display each object? also lenght-1 is wrong i think

Comment: The console shows the length 12 (which is correct), then shows only one time:
undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: this.locations is object type are you sure about that?

Comment: Here is interface for location:
interface Location {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    Country: string;
    Airport: string;
}

Comment: The class from server side is:
public class Location
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Airport { get; set; }
    }

Comment: what is the console.log(this.locations); result?

Comment: @Akkus the object is all there when I log the this.locations as you said: -it shows an array of 12 elements when I drop down the array I see all the values (they are there, they are no undefined, when I drop down the array in the console I can see all objects)

Comment: I have added a screenshot that shows the problem

Comment: ok the problem is ID, Name, Country, Airport..

change like this id, name, country, airport

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. But why did the property names got changed??

Comment: cheers man :) like my correct comment please